# Convert DYMO .lwl files to .label files in code

Tags: .net, label, file-type

I am currently working on an existing project that uses a DYMO label writer to print badges. The badges use different badge templates based on the users workflow. To set the fields of the badge I load it, then set the fields to the correct text. The issue is that all of the Badge templates are saved as .lwl files. These .lwl files are used throughout the software and I would like to be able to not have to change everything over to use the new .label format.

I would like to know is there is a way in C# and with the .NET DYMO Label Framework to open a .lwl file or some way convert a .lwl to a .label file in code. I am currently doing:

`DYMO.Label.Framework.ILabel DymoLabel = DYMO.Label.Framework.Label.Open(Badge);`

This works fine when opening a .label file, but throws an exception when I try to open a .lwl file. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, Do you find solution for this issue?

Comment: That's a negative. I haven't had to implement the change yet so hopefully I find out soon. I will update this post if I do. If you can find anything it would be greatly appreciated! Please up-vote the question to try and get it some more recognition please!

Answer (score 0):

Very late, but there is an easy way:

Start the DYMO software, than just dubble click the *.LWL file in your file explorer.
It will open in the DYMO software. Just save it there. It will be converted in a *.LABEL file automatically...